# CSS3 resize - Can you move the resize icon?

Tags: html, css

I am using the CSS3 property "resize: both" to allow the user to resize a div I have. But for some reason, the resize triangle that you click and drag with to resize the window is pushed outside of the div, and is hardly visible to users. Is there a way that I can position this resize triangle with CSS to make it more squarely in the corner of my window?

Comment: can u post some code? or fiddle if possible

Comment: @Kishore you might want to explain that a fiddle is a "saved" http://jsfiddle.net minimally working example that demonstrates the issue the OP is seeing. When "save" is pressed, the JSFiddle website produces a static URL that anyone else can use to see your progress.

Comment: I could try to do a fiddle, but I think the error is coming from some bootstrap classes that are aligning the triangle in a funny way. Can I use external libraries on fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With css you can change the image of the cursor,

```
cursor: url(cursor.cur),default;
```